# MYSQL: Query to get previous and next video ID?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysql

I am developing a video website (`PHP - MYSQL`), just like youtube, in which I want to provide the functionality of `Next` video and `Previous` video. Let's say I am currently on `videoId: 234` so Next and Previous video links will point to `videoId: 233` and `235` respecively.

My table structure is as follows:

```
videoId      videoName    videoURL      IsActive
-----------------------------------------------------
1            Love world    love-world        1
2            Hello world   hellow-world      1
3            World news    world-news        0
4            The web       the-web           1
5            Google web    google-web        1
6            Internet      internet          1
```

`IsActive a bool (0,1) type column` is basically tells that video is viewable on website or not. If its 0 - notviewable and 1 - viewable

Now there are two type of situations which I though are:

- When I am browsing through videoId: 4 then I want to run a query to get the the next and previous video id means 2 and 5 respectively, 3 is not because it is disabled.
- Other condition would be When I am browsing through videoId: 1 then query should return only one record which is 2, because there is no previous record, same in the case of last record.

Please tell me how to make query for this?

Thanks

Comment: MAking a bunch of assumptions here, but Consider what will happen if:
A user views the "Hello World" video, 
An admin(or who ever) marks "The Web" as inactive.
that user clicks next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM videos AS c 
 WHERE (VideoId = (SELECT MAX(VideoId) FROM videos WHERE VideoId < c.VideoId AND IsActive = 1)
    OR  VideoId = (SELECT MIN(VideoId) FROM videos WHERE VideoId > c.VideoId AND IsActive = 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
 SELECT * FROM videos WHERE videoId > :id AND IsActive = 1 LIMIT 1
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM videos WHERE videoId < :id AND IsActive = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the next one

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM vedios WHERE vedio > :id AND IsActive = 1")
$stmt->execute(array("id" => $id));
$all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And change > to < for previous. If `count($all)` return 0, then you don't have a next/previous video.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to fetch both next and previous in two rows using a single query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Completely untested, but this will give you a normal row with two additional columns 'nextID' and 'prevID'. If one of them is null, then there isn't one.

```
SELECT v.*, n.id AS nextID, p.id AS prevID
  FROM vedios v
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT vn.id FROM vedios vn WHERE vn.id > v.id AND isActive = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) n
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT vp.id FROM vedios vp WHERE vp.id < v.id AND isActive = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) p
```

If you have any issues / errors with it, let me know and I'll test it properly.

Answer (score 0):

best query string :

```
SELECT
        (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `id` < `t`.`id`) as `_prev_id`,
        (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `table` WHERE `id` > `t`.`id`) as `_next_id`

  FROM `table` `t`

 WHERE `t`.`id` = '1'

 LIMIT 1
```