# Get previous & next id value of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE name='test'
```

Once the above query is executed I want the previous and next id values. Ofcourse they will not be incremental.  How can I get the next and previous ids based on the where condition.

Comment: "Next" and "Previous" by what sort order / key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL: Query to get previous and next video ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081851/mysql-query-to-get-previous-and-next-video-id)

Comment: @Pekka웃 by the where=name. There is no order by desc/asc.

Comment: @h2ooooooo  That example is not even close to what I have asked, please read the question again.

Comment: But the query you show is selecting only one record, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes.  Can I do it with one query, though its possible with 2 queries

Comment: @Jean by what sort order would you determine which record is the next, and which one is the previous? Do you have an `id` column?

Comment: @Pekka웃 There is an 'ID' column.  But the records are grouped by name='test'

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
 select * from Tablename where name = 'test' AND id = (select min(id) from Tablename  where id > 4) OR id = (select max(id) from Tablename  where id < 4)
```

Comment: Can I not do without 2 diff queries?

Comment: `echo $row_next_prev['next']` gives null

Comment: i m not sure but in single query something like this.. check edited code.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    TableName 
WHERE 
    id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM TableName where id > 2) 
    AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName where id < 2)
```

**OR** you can use `Limit`

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE `id` > 2 ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE `id` < 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Need to do it in a single query.

Comment: @Jean check other query. you can use `LIMIT` also

Comment: Assuming the current id=36223, the previous for test purpose is 36222 and next 36224, but the return value is 36215.

Comment: @Jean I think there is no records on 36222 and 36224, why dont you try this query on nearest id like 1 to 10?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use mysql_data_seek() if you are using php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php